# Getting length of variable that counts elements with class, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently making a memory game, and oddly enough, whenever I try and get the length of the number of elements within the cardClicked class, it doesn't return anything other than 0. I believe it has to do with when it is searching for the class, and when the elements have the class added. There is a similar post to this, but the answers don't apply, to my knowledge. Thanks.
The goal is 
1. Element is clicked
2. Class of cardClicked is added
3. It searches for the number of elements with that class
4. returns the amount
5. When it reaches two I have another function I want to use, but I cant get it past 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It doesn't work because starting with the line `var clicked =`, that line and all the following ones are outside your click handler and they only run once when the page is loaded. You're fiddle [fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/br0enkg7/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the click handler before the check is made

```
$('.card').click(function(){
  $(this).find("span").toggleClass( "cardText" );
  $(this).toggleClass( "cardClicked" );
  console.log(clicked);
  var clicked = document.getElementsByClassName('cardClicked');
  var amount = clicked.length;
  console.log(amount);
  if(amount == 2){
    console.log('good');
  }
});
```

Now you are checking if the length is two

Comment: Yep, Thats it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Made a second listener for every click. This so you can update the values in each click. In this listener you can put you game logic to validate if they are the same

```
$('.card').click(function() {
    var clicked = document.getElementsByClassName('cardClicked');
    var amount = clicked.length;
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount == 2) {
      console.log('good');
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [
    "Potato",
    "Tomato",
    "Strawberry",
    "Pencil",
    "Blueberry",
    "Raspberry",
    "Lettuce",
    "Steak"
  ];

  items = shuffle(items)
  //console.log(items);

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="card"/>').html('<span class="cardText">' + items[i] + '</span>').appendTo('.board');
  };

  items = shuffle(items);

  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('<div class="card"/>').html('<span class="cardText">' + items[i] + '</span>').appendTo('.board');
  };


  $('.card').click(function() {
    $(this).find("span").toggleClass("cardText");
    $(this).toggleClass("cardClicked");
  });

  $('.card').click(function() {
    var clicked = document.getElementsByClassName('cardClicked');
    var amount = clicked.length;
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount == 2) {
      console.log('good');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.board {
  height: 630px;
  width: 630px;
  background-color: #DAD6D6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -315px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 157.5px;
}

.card {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 14.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #B6455F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.cardText {
  display: none;
}

.cardClicked {}

.notHidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <script src="game.js"></script>
  <link href="game.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="board">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS part `document.getElementsByClassName('cardClicked');` was not inside of the `click` event listener.

Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/o0xmcapx/55/

By the way, why you mix pure JS with jQuery? Instead of `document.getElementByClassName` inside of a jquery function, keep using the jQuery selector `$('.cardClicked')`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dong that work outside the click handler.

```
$('.card').click(function(){
  $(this).find("span").toggleClass( "cardText" );
    $(this).toggleClass( "cardClicked" );
    console.log(clicked);

    var clicked = document.getElementsByClassName('cardClicked');
    var amount = clicked.length;
    console.log(amount);
    if(amount == 2){
        console.log('good');
    }
  });
});
```